# How can I stretch background on the whole window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I'm trying to stretch the background to fill the whole window with HTML/CSS.
I've seen a few solutions for this but they don't work.
Every solution i encounter won't work on all the browsers, either Chrome won't stretch it, or IE won't stretch it, and if they both do, firefox will be the problematic one.

Does anyone have a working solution, that will work on all browsers ? (don't mind some javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way to do this without creating an img element, and setting its z-order to the bottom and then customizing the width of that. [This page](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_stretch_background_image.cfm) has details.

Edit: In the link it says to use `position: fixed;`. This will in only work in older versions of IE if you specify a doctype. Using absolute is a simple workaround as long as the element is a direct child of the body.

Comment: This doesn't work for IE8 ... Background image appears above the content (separately)

Comment: Just the background div should be Absolute, not fixed.. add that to your answer

Comment: I see what you mean, good to see you got it sorted. It should work with fixed if you declared a doctype btw.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a little while ago and I found that this website http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm had a very nicely written tutorial which explains it well, plus it worked for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

http://reisio.com/temp/stretch/

Answer (score 0):

write a css for that in which the background image will be in body.like

```
body {
    background-image: url("/images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center top ;
     }
```

This will keep the total image in the body.Try this hope it will work.